# PHP: call function by text in var?

Tags: php

I want to make a plugin system for my simple cms. I need to execute some code if some text construction like [call=plugin1] is found in 'page.html'. The content of this page is read and stored in variable.

```
$page_content= '<div>the result of function [call=plugin1] </div>';
 //some code to embed the result of fn 
 echo  $page_content; //finally
```

Comment: can u please explain the requirement in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it rather easily using str_replace:

```
$page_content = "a bunch of stuff... [call=plugin] ... and more stuff";
$page_content = str_replace('[call=plugin]', your_plugin_function(), $page_content);
echo $page_content;
```

You can also use str_replace_all if the substring will appear more than once.
You can also use multiple replacements to handle multiple substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really understand your question. Is it possible to put the condition in a if, like:

```
$page_content="";
if(call==plugin1)
    {
    $page_content= '<div>the result of function [call=plugin1] </div>';
     //some code to embed the result of fn 
    }
     echo  $page_content; //finally
```

Comment: `if(call=plugin1)` careful; that's an assignment. `if(call==plugin1)` is a comparison. as per original http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35707084/1

Comment: you're right, I just copy/paste his code! I correct it! ;)

Comment: Hi, i edit my question